# Analysing a multiple choice question

Tags: chi-squared-test

I asked my questionnaire's respondents whether they are aware of a particular subject and provided them with a list of four statements to choose from. I need to analyse whether their awareness differs among these  respondents, say by comparing this question with the demographics (variables having an ordinal or nominal scale).

I would like to know which statistical test I should use. Can I use the Chi squared test?

Comment: Did you give them 4 yes/no questions (one for each subject)? Or did you give them 1 question with a "check all that apply" format?

Comment: I gave them a list of 4 statements to choose from (by ticking the best response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need multinomial logistic regression. The dependent variable will be the choice and the independent variables will be the demographics